# What should I do if I want to use large datasets that can't load into the memory with TensorFlow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, bigdata

I want to use a large dataset that cannot load into the memory once to train a model with TensorFlow. But I don't know what exacty I should do.

I have read some great posts about `TFRecords` file format and the official document. Bus I still can't figure it out.

Is there a complete solution plan with TensorFlow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [`tf.TextLineReader`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/io_ops) which in conjunction with `tf.train.string_input_producer` allows you to load data from multiple files on disk (if your dataset is large enough that it needs to be spread out into multiple files).

See https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#reading_from_files

Code snippet from the link above:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["file0.csv", "file1.csv"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Default values, in case of empty columns. Also specifies the type of the
# decoded result.
record_defaults = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = tf.decode_csv(
    value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
features = tf.stack([col1, col2, col3, col4])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for     filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["file0.csv", "file1.csv"])

reader = tf.TextLineReader()
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Default values, in case of empty columns. Also specifies the type of the
# decoded result.
record_defaults = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 = tf.decode_csv(
    value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
features = tf.stack([col1, col2, col3, col4])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  # Start populating the filename queue.
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for i in range(1200):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)i in range(1200):
    # Retrieve a single instance:
    example, label = sess.run([features, col5])

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. But what if there are **many columns** in CSV file? I have to write many col1, col2, col3 ... and so on? And how to read data from binary files?

Comment: @secsilm yes, you need `col1`, `col2` etc for each column in your CSV. Keep in mind `col1` is just a variable name so you could give it a more mnemonic name like `price` or something. For binary files see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/FixedLengthRecordReader

Answer (score 1):

Normally you use a batch wise training anyways so you can load the data on the fly. For example for images:

```
for bid in nrBatches:
     batch_x, batch_y = load_data_from_hd(bid)
     train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y})
```

So you load every batch on the fly and only load the data which you need to load at any given moment. Naturally your training time will increase while using the harddisk instead of memory to load data.